# How to use the jquery autocomplete input tag that you added to the innerHTML

Tags: jquery, autocomplete

I can use autocomplete input made html tag. 
However, I can not use autocomplete input tag made innerHTML tag.

oCell1.innerHTML = ..input type='text' class='nbtext' maxlength='500' name='rc_client' value='' ..

```
          $(function() {    
    $( ".newnbtext" ).autocomplete({ 
        source: client_arr,
            minLength: 1,
            messages: { 
                              noResults: '',
                results: function() {}
            }
    });
```

---

...input type="text" class="newnbtext" maxlength="500" name="rc_client" value="<%=beanGet(hmItems,"RC_CLIENT","")%>"

Comment: Is this a typo? `class='nbtext'` (first code block).

Comment: half assed...keydown...

Answer (score 1):

You need to initiate the plugin after the field is added

```
oCell1.innerHTML = "<input type='text' class='nbtext' maxlength='500' name='rc_client' value='' >";

//initiate the plugin in the new input field
$(oCell1).find('input').autocomplete({
    source: client_arr,
    minLength: 1,
    messages: {
        noResults: '',
        results: function () {}
    }
});
```

When you initiate a plugin, it will be initiated on those elements which exists at the time of the initiation code execution. For any element that is added later you need to initiate it after the element is created.

Comment: function segment_addRow() {
.....
oCell1.innerHTML....
}

oCell1 is a local variable.
sorry....I don't understand.

Comment: @지상우 sorry... what do you mean?

Comment: What are local variables that can be used inde oCell1?